# Unable to play media on website

Tags: flash, plugins, video-player, media, music-player

I seem to be able to play the media on every website except `datpiff.com` flash player.  It's really strange and not sure if the issue is mine or the websites. I run Ubuntu 12.04.5.  If it is my issue, can anyone suggest the correct fix?

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using ? Have you tried to install chrome browser ?! Use firefox to download chrome at http://google.com/chrome and then install with Ubuntu package manager the downloaded bundle or you take the package manager in the left side of unity and install there chrome directly. This is easier and more safe than to install flash-player manually (flash-player is not supported any more as single package).

Comment: This answer asks for additional info and is a borderline comment. I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)